# Some times JQuery ajax didn't executed after redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function which executes a jQuery ajax request. After this function, the web page will be redirected to another url, but sometimes the web page redirects before executing the ajax request.

```
executeAjax();
doRedirect();
```

Comment: can you provide that complete code on what have you done?

Answer (score 1):

A benefit of Ajax is executing without delay next commands.

So, you should add your redirect into "done" or "always" function of ajax.

```js
    url = "https://www.google.com.vn/";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
    })
    .done(function($response) {
        console.log("success");
        doRedirect();
    })
    .always(function($response) {
        console.log("always");
        doRedirect();
    })
    ;
    
    function doRedirect(){
       location.href = "https://www.google.co.jp/maps/@35.6550509,139.8022144,15z?hl=ja";
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The advantage(in your case, problem) of ajax is that it is an asynchronous operation. That means the ajax request will not block the code after the ajax function. In other words in your case, the `doRedirect();` will work without waiting for the `executeAjax();` to complete.

The best method to overcome this is to use the `success` property of the ajax method. The `success` method requires a callback function and it always fires only after the ajax method is done successfully.

If your requirement is to redirect regardless of whether ajax is success or failed, you can use the `complete` property of ajax

***Redirects when AJAX request succeeds***

```
     $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'JSON',
        success:function(data){
                doRedirect();//redirects only when the ajax request is successfully completed
               }
    });
```

***Redirects when AJAX request succeeds or fails***

```
     $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'JSON',
        complete:function(){ 
                doRedirect();//redirects even the ajax requests failed
               }
    });
```